# Does stopPropagation also prevent other handlers on the same element from running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, jquery-events

I know that `stopPropagation()` prevents the event from reaching the DOM elements that wrap the current element. Does it also prevent this event from being delivered to other handlers on the same element?

To give an example, I have my own click handler defined on an element. In addition I am also using this [jQuery Context Menu](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/) plugin which handles a `mousedown+(testbutton == 2)+mouseup` and uses `stopPropagation()` after mouse(up|down) and this seems to disable my click handlers. If I comment these two calls in the plugin source, my click handlers and the context menu work correctly. This seems to suggest that `stopPropagation()` and `stopImmediatePropgation()` do the same thing. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `stopPropagation` doesn't stop other handlers of the same event, but in this specific case it does. If you use it in the `mousedown` event, it will prevent the `click` event.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v6ges/

```
$('div').mousedown(function(e){ alert(0); e.stopPropagation(); });
$('div').click(function(e){ alert(1); e.stopPropagation(); });
$('div').click(function(e){ alert(2); e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Only the `mousedown` event is triggered. If you comment out the `mousedown` event binding, both of the `click` events are triggered.